# как сделать такую обводку с треугольником на hover?

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать такой эффект, как быть? 
вот код, который у меня есть. Первый скрин то, как нужно, второй - то что у меня получилось.

```css
.advantages__link:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #9a4ba3;
 color: white;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 border: none;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можете также добавить HTM и пояснить в чём именно должна быть анимация? Что именно должно происходить на hover?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov вот html элемент
<li class="advantages__li"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="advantages__link tablink">Содержание вредных веществ</a></li>
эта обводка с треугольником должна появляться на ховер

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, это в вопрос, а также скажите что именно должно происходить на hover? Если можно отредактируйте вопрос так, чтобы по оглавлению можно было бы понять о чём идёт речь. "Этот эффект", "как сделать это" неясно, что имеется ввиду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-color: #c05eca;
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 40px;
  margin: 25px 16px 0px 0px;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: #9a4ba1;
}

div:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: 100%;
    top: 0 ;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 19px solid transparent;
    border-left: 16px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 19px solid transparent;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
div:hover:before {
    border-left: 16px solid #9a4ba1;
}
```

```html
<div>Содержание вредных веществ</div>
```

Comment: Тут же я так понял, что что-то должно происходить на hover, а не просто вывести блок с треугольником.

Comment: Вадим, Вы правильно поняли)

Comment: Тут по сути сделано, что я и хотел, поэтому удаляю свой ответ.

Comment: супер, спасибо большое